# Windows 11: pen side button not working as previously

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-11, pen, stylus

I'm using Windows 11 Insider Preview 10.0.22622.290 on my Lenovo [Flex 5i 15](https://www.lenovo.com/il/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/IdeaPad-Flex-5-15ITL-05/p/88IPF501454?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

The pen I'm using is the Lenovo [Active Pen 2](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/acc100370). It has 2 side buttons and up until about two months ago, the upper button, when used, would function as '**[barrel button](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht508862-how-to-use-the-buttons-from-your-lenovo-digital-pen)**' which would function as right click on most things.

In some apps such as OneNote (and Microsoft Whiteboard) it would activate *lasso select* and this is the important part for me as I use OneNote as my notebook app for university.

#### What I think happend:

It seems to me as this functionality was broken by some Windows update not long ago but I can't figure out which one and sadly I cannot roll back windows far enough to find out since my laptop had a bios update and doesn't want me to roll back windows to before it.

#### What I've tried:

In the Lenovo pen software the settings the button is mapped as 'barrel button' by default and I double checked it still is.

I would be good to mention that I have **another Active Pen 2** (for emergencies) and that the problem happens on both of them and that every other part of the pen still works the same:

- The bluetooth button on the top of the pen.
- The lower side button still functions as eraser.
- The pen itself works.

I tried disabling its software and tried to update it but nothing changed.
Tried to mp the barrel button function to the lower side button and nothing.
It almost feels like the '*barrel button*' was removed from Windows.

Setting the button to function as right click does not solve the problem since it turns to a mouse cursor when doing so and does not work as lasso select in onenote
It seems like pressing the button just registers as a normal click.

I uploaded this to Microsoft feedback hub too: https://aka.ms/AAi701h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue. Try installing this driver: https://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Lenovo driver could help :
[Active Pen Driver for Windows 11 (64-bit) -ThinkBook 14s Yoga ITL](https://support.lenovo.com/za/en/downloads/ds552403-active-pen-driver-for-windows-11-64-bit-thinkbook-14s-yoga-itl).

If it doesn't work, uninstall the driver, then enter your
serial number in "Find Your Product" box to find more drivers.
Don't install drivers for devices if they are functioning correctly.

If nothing helps, call or email Lenovo Support and ask for
a solution.

Comment: I already tried to install the Active pen driver... nothing changed